# Microsoft Word Page Number Location

Tags: microsoft-word, documents, documentation, page-numbers

I am working on a Macbook, and I am working on word 16.57.
I added some page numbers at the bottom right of the pages, but the numbers show way too high up in the page. It is the first time I see it placing the numbers that far up, and I have been unable to set them back to default. I can manually select the number and change its location, but I just want the placing it had before.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I doubt a new Normal.dotm will help but it won't hurt, so long as you do not delete the old one. How are you placing the number? Ctrl+Shift+P inserts a page number field on a Mac. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#Function

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a new Word Normal.dotm to have a check.

1. First close Word.
2. In **Finder** please hold the <kbd>**Option**</kbd> key while you open the **Go** menu.
3. Look in `~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/Templates`, find the `Normal.dotm`, then move it to other location as a backup.
4. Then open Word to check. This file will be automatically generated when Word is reopened.